# If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically

Tags: sql

```
TABLE NAME STATION
____________________
|FIELD|TYPE        |
----- |-------------
ID    | NUMBER 
CITY  | VARCHAR2(21)
STATE | VARCHAR2(2)
LAT_N | NUMBER 
LONG_W| NUMBER
```

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
ORDER BY CITY
LIMIT 1;
```

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  Find the city with the shortest name?

Comment: *What is wrong with this query?*: you tell us, so we can try and help. Please clarify your problem statement. Sample data, current and desired results would also help.

Comment: _Smallest city_ - I'd consider population instead (or perhaps area.)